# Is it possible to use values from one view's column as condition in second view's column?

Tags: t-sql, view, case

I have one column in view which is created based on random select of x per cent in the source table and then I would need to use a value from this column as CASE WHEN condition to create second view's column. Is it somehow possible?

```sql
CREATE VIEW view 
AS
SELECT 
  [ItemId] = CASE
    WHEN Id in (SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT Id FROM SourceTable ORDER BY NEWID()) THEN 2
    ELSE 1
  END,
  [SecondItemId] = CASE
    WHEN [ItemId] = 1 THEN 11
    WHEN [ItemId] = 2 THEN 222
  END
FROM SourceTable
```

Comment: There are very few guarantees given by SQL Server about *how often* it'll evaluate certain constructs, such as `NEWID()`, for any particular row. Unfortunately, most solutions to this sort of problem require tools that aren't available in views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got this correctly, but I get, that you want to *compute* a value and use this value in another computation.

`APPLY` allows us, to create additional columns to our set, which can be taken as a *row-wise computed* variable. Try this:

```
SELECT A.SomeRandomItemId
      ,CASE A.SomeRandomItemId WHEN 1 THEN 11
                               WHEN 2 THEN 222
       END AS TheDependantItemId
FROM SourceTable
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN Id in (SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT Id FROM SourceTable ORDER BY NEWID()) THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) A(SomeRandomItemId);
```

As Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out in a comment, we never know for sure, how the engine will work down the statement. Using random elements in our queries can lead to unexpected results. But in this case, I would not expect a big surprise...